# How to iterate thru all google cloud kms keys in an organization without running into read quotas?

Tags: quota, google-cloud-kms

I am trying to find out if there are keys which have versions that are older than one year and setting their rotation period to 24 hours from now. Unfortunately, each list keyring call is counting as a key.read which there is a quota which is very small (~300/min) is there a way to work around these quotas besides increasing them? I am trying to run this code periodically in a cloud function so there is a runtime limit such that I cannot just wait for the quota to reset.

```
def list_keys(project):
    client = kms_v1.KeyManagementServiceClient()
    #this location list is based on a running of `gcloud kms locations list` and represents a where a key could be created
    location_list = ['asia','asia-east1','asia-east2','asia-northeast1','asia-northeast2',
                     'asia-south1','asia-southeast1','australia-southeast1','eur4','europe',
                     'europe-north1','europe-west1','europe-west2','europe-west3','europe-west4',
                     'europe-west6','global','nam4','northamerica-northeast1','southamerica-east1',
                     'us','us-central1','us-east1','us-east4','us-west1','us-west2']

    for location in location_list:
        key_ring_parent = client.location_path(project,location)
        key_ring_list = client.list_key_rings(key_ring_parent)
        for key_ring in key_ring_list:
            parent = client.key_ring_path(project,location,format_keyring_name(key_ring.name))
            for key in client.list_crypto_keys(parent):
                start_time = key.primary.create_time # need to use primary to get latest version of the key
                now = time.time()
                now_seconds = int(now)
                elapsed = now_seconds - start_time.seconds
                next_rotate_age =(key.next_rotation_time.seconds - now_seconds) + elapsed
                days_elapsed = elapsed/3600/24
                print(key.name," is this many days old: ",  days_elapsed)
                print(key.name," will be this many days old when it is scheduled to rotate: ",  next_rotate_age/3600/24)
                #if the key is a year old set it to rotate tomorrow
                if days_elapsed > 364:
                    #client.
                    update_mask = kms_v1.types.UpdateCryptoKeyRequest.update_mask
                    #print(update_mask)
                    new_rotation_time  = now_seconds + (3600*24) # 1 day from now because can't set less than 24 hrs notice on certain keys
                    key.next_rotation_time.seconds = new_rotation_time

                    update_mask =  {'paths':{'next_rotation_time': new_rotation_time}} 
                    print(client.update_crypto_key(key, update_mask))
```

Answer (score 2):

Is [cloud asset inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/exporting-to-cloud-storage) an option? You could run something like

```
$ gcloud asset export --organization YOUR_ORG_ID      \
      --asset_types cloudkms.googleapis.com/CryptoKey \
      --content-type RESOURCE                         \
      --output-path "gs://YOUR_BUCKET/NEW_FILE"
```

The output file will contain the full [CryptoKey resource](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.keyRings.cryptoKeys) for every single key in the organization so you don't need to send a ton of List/Get requests to the KMS API.

Comment: In particular the output file will contain `"createTime"` and `"nextRotationTime"`. Running an inventory request, say, twice a year (for keys with a rotation period of one year) will provide complete control over the key expiration dates.

Answer (score 1):

Having looking into your request, it would seem that it would not be possible to work around the quotas besides increasing them.

I would suggest looking at these following documentations on the following:

1. [Resource quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas)
2. [Working with Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota)
3. [Quotas and Limits](https://cloud.google.com/interconnect/quotas)

These documents should provide you with the information you need on quotas.